# Automating a navigation bar in HTML

Tags: html

I have an `html` page called `foo.html` with a navigation bar as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="../public/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="../src/bar.html">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="../src/baz.html">Baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want this in **all** of the `html` files, so for the `bar.html` file it should be:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="../public/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../src/foo.html">Foo</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="../src/baz.html">Baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

etc.

Is there anyway to automate this such that within a given file, say `foo.html`, it knows it is active page.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: You will need to use the PHP `inlcude()` function or JavaScript for this. Please try either one of those and if you faced a roadblock, let us know what you have done so far and what the roadblock is.

Comment: @AndrewL64 Will give this a go in `PHP`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You need to have a state of your application for such cases. Like `navState = { page1: true, page2: false, page3: false }. You will also need to provide handlers that will change the state on user actions (events)